# stripshlashes not working on my server

Tags: php, mysql

I have the most weird thing from all my PHP experience. I have a phpBB forum. When I replay to a topic(Only then), `if` the subject is `"Re: APPEL D'OFFRES"`, I get a
"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access `/zonemembres/posting.php` on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

I started a debug process ans saw that the problem is on a `stripslashes` function. the script makes "`Re: APPEL D\'OFFRES`"(so it can add it to database I suppose) and after that, it applies the "`stripshlashes`" function. On my local pc, the function return the corect value:"Re: APPEL D'OFFRES"(without "\"), but on my server it throws that error. Also, I've tried a lot of other combinations that worked: "Re: APPEL D\'OFFRS" THIS WORKED!! What is going on? Also text like "`Re: AAPEL D\'OFFRES`" works.

And one more think, the error is thrown when I try to "`echo`" the stripped text.
`$result = stripslashes($result);`   -> no error

`echo $result;` -> here comes the error.

It drives me crazy. Does someone have an ideea?

EDIT:

I've also checked the file permissions. Not a problem there. I repeat, for anyother subject anme, it works.

Comment: Actual error in error.log, and have you considered disabling magic_quotes and using the right database escaping function? Might be easier than randomly applying and deapplying backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Your server configuration must have 'magic_quotes_gpc' enabled.

See documentation page for more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

It is a really bad practice, and deprecated since PHP 5.3.0.
You should disable them with an .htaccess file, take a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Answer (score 0):

you should disable magic quotes. put this in your .htaccess file.

```
php_value magic_quotes 0
php_flag magic_quotes off
php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0 
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```